# One website, 2 journeys

Tags: user-journey, journey-map

I have a business website, which has 2 subdomains, one for individuals and one for businesses.

I was just going to simply supply a landing page which allowed the visitor to select which they are (with some details on each) then direct them to the subdomain.

Is this the best way?
Should I allow people to switch back via a button or similar?

Ideas would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

This is how [conrad](https://conrad.de) (a German webshop for electronics) does it. There is a toggle with a popover nudging the user to make  a selection between private  or business. Text reads "Are you a business customer? This setting adjusts the product range and prices to your needs."

I like that you can still have a look at their shop in the background and click on things. If you press the toggle it will automatically change the prices and some content on the page without reload.

(I am not in any way affiliated with them, it is just the only example I could find.)

[image: webshop with toggle and popover]

Comment: Thanks got that..I’ll check out Conrad…

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its likely you'd want to allow people to switch back, as users are sometimes making mistakes as well as just being curious.

 
In your case it seems to me it could be beneficial to have in header or footer "For Business customers" or "For individuals" CTA button, oposite of the role.

 
Most of the website contextually have landing page thats general / for all roles and then only sections per role. But if you have it like that you need to provide some sort of switch.

 
Also it would be desirable to have same design (or at least same design patterns and positioning) on both roles.

Comment: Nice one…thanks